# StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges not calling didupdatedLocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager

I am developing an iOS 7 app that uses location. I never get the location updated. If I do the same with `startUpdatingLocation` it works good. I have read the documentation and I don't know where is the problem.
The location is enabled for the app, and it ask you if you want to enabled it the first time I run the app. Also the location icon in the status bar is not showed.

Update: In the simulator it works, it gives me an updated location. Why it doesn't work in the device?

It's only going to be used in a class, here is the configuration.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ClassLocation : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
}
```

Setting the property in the .h and in the .m the synthesize

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *localizacionManager;

@synthesize localizacionManager;
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
localizacionManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[localizacionManager setDelegate:self];
[localizacionManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];
[localizacionManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

And the two delegate methods:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error.description);
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    NSLog(@"Location updated");
}
```

Comment: Is the `didUpdateLocations:` method really _never_ called or maybe only once and then it's not called any more? The method is called at most once every 5 minutes, so that might be the reason. Also, does your phone change its location significantly when you are testing? If not, you can use the device simulator to simulate location changes (Simulator menu --> Debug --> Location)

Comment: It's never called because i put a NSLog and a breakpoint and it's never called. I don't change my location, but it should at least call "didUpdateLocations" once, as Apple documentation says

Comment: Yes, that's right, this method is usually called at least once in the beginning, then it takes a while (about 5 min) until it is called again, that's strange indeed!

Comment: Trying it in the simulator, it works. Then why not in the device? Thanks for your answers Nikolas!

Comment: @saimonx did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Add a key to your Info.plist and request authorization from the location manager asking it to start.

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

You need to request authorization for the corresponding location method.

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]

[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]
```

Answer (score 1):

The same happens to me in iOS 7. I presume it's due to the last location being cached; if the current location has no significant changes compared to the last one, the delegate never gets called.

You can access the last cached location by using the "location" property of the `CLLocationManager` :

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic, copy) CLLocation *location ;
```

Hope this helps.